# Create a large number of contracts with different addresses

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, ganache

I'm developing a performance test where I check the time a gateway spends to find a contract in a blockchain. I'm using ganache-cli to simulate the blockchain, my doubts are:

1) Is it possible to generate 100 contracts at one time using the truffle? Should each of these contracts have a different name or can all have the same name?

2) When I use the `truffle migrate` command I can get the addresses of each contract in the terminal that is running ganache. How do I use web3js to get the contract that I know the addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On blockchain there is no such thing as contract name.  Deployed contract has only address, balance, nonce, byte code, and storage.

You may create many contracts in one transaction like this:

```
contract Foo {
  // Some stuff to be deployed multiple times
}

contract Bar {
  event FooAddress (address indexed addr);

  // Deploy n instances of Foo contract and then self destruct
  constructor (uint256 n) public {
    while (n --> 0) {
      emit FooAddress (address (new Foo ()));
    }
    selfdestruct (msg.sender);
  }
}
```

You may get addresses of deployed contracts by querying `FooAddress` events from `Bar` contract.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm using ganache, so is returned the contract address everytime a contract is mined. So my doubt is: How can I retrieve a contract status using the address that i know?

Comment: Basically what I want to know is: If I know the transaction address, no matter how many blocks the blockchain has, The time to change the status of a contract will be the same if the blockchain has only 10 blocks or 1 block...

Comment: What do you mean by contract status?

Comment: perform a `getFunction()` from a contract.